# Get new column value after UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **A** and **B**. My application continuously executes transactions that consist of:

1. Update a row in table **A**.
2. Insert a row in table **B** that defines the update done in step 1.

(The two steps belong to the same transaction to keep table **A** and **B** mutually consistent.)

At any time, for a given state of a row in table **A**, I need to fetch the corresponding row in table **B**. Therefore, I add a version column to table **A** and table **B**. When the transaction is executed, the updated row in table **A** has its version column incremented. However, I need this new value for the `INSERT` executed in step 2.

Is there a way to get the new version value after the `UPDATE`?

Thanks, Mickael

Comment: After update the latest version info will be present in builtin/magic NEW table which can be accessed by the way I mentioned. want to know more .. read MySQL documentation.

Comment: @Rahul I didn't find any NEW table. It's not in any of the internal MySQL schemas.